# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, sms, bulksms

I m trying to embed Bulk SMS API in my website ...But the code is giving 401

ASPX :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>%> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<head id="Head1" runat="server"> 
  <title>Send SMS</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <form id="form2" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
    </div> 
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

ASPX.CS

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
     public void SendSMS()
    {
        UriBuilder urlBuilder = new UriBuilder();
        urlBuilder.Host = "IP";
        urlBuilder.Port = port;

        string UserName = "username";
        string password = "password";
        string PhoneNumber = "919999999999";
        string Text = "Testing";
        string Sender = "sender name";

        urlBuilder.Query = string.Format("user=" + UserName + "password=" + password + "PhoneNumber=" + PhoneNumber + "&Text=" + Text + "&Sender=" + Sender);

        HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(urlBuilder.ToString(), false));
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(httpReq.GetResponse());
    }



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendSMS();
    }

}
```

Comment: IP ,port ,username , password ,9999999999 , sender name
are all substitutions..

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
    urlBuilder.Host = "IP";
    urlBuilder.Port = port;
```

Is telling your `HttpWebRequest` to go to http://IP:port  as in literally the server IP.  http://IP doesn't exist, you need to put the actual hostname there, like "www.google.com"...whatever server you're trying to hit.

Comment: @KK - So there's no path?  Just `http://host:port/?user=usernamepassword=passwordPhoneNumber=91999999999&Text=Testing&Sender=sender%20name`?  Note: you probably wanted some more `&` between your query parameters there.

Comment: ohh shit ..i forgot & at 2 locations Thanx man ...i wasted lots of time on this ..thanx again ..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in:

```
urlBuilder.Query = string.Format("user=" + UserName + "password=" + password + "PhoneNumber=" + PhoneNumber + "&Text=" + Text + "&Sender=" + Sender);
```

You're missing a few &s. Should probably be something like:

```
urlBuilder.Query = string.Format("user=" + UserName + "&password=" + password + "&PhoneNumber=" + PhoneNumber + "&Text=" + Text + "&Sender=" + Sender);
```

Edit: Also there is no reason to be using `string.Format()` here. This would work the same:

```
urlBuilder.Query = "user=" + UserName + "&password=" + password + "&PhoneNumber=" + PhoneNumber + "&Text=" + Text + "&Sender=" + Sender;
```